# Update table with wildcard?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

We're using login by IP on +200 wordpress sites. Since we recently moved, we need to change the IP address. 
I used this code snippet in ManageWP

```
<?php

    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query( 
        "UPDATE wp_UNIQUE_PREFIX_ip_based_login
        SET start='X', end='Y'"
     );


?>
```

but I just found that all WP installations has a unique prefix. So I'm trying to combine the above SQL command with a select with wildcard.
I'm trying to find all tables that ends with "ip_based_login", and set the start and end column with the new IP address. Here's what I've got so far.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_ip_based_login'
    SET start='X', end='Y'
```

I'm getting this error `Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'SET start='x', end='y'' at line 4`

**EDIT:**
Thanks to RiggsFolly, I used $wpdb->prefix to concatenate with the end of the table. So I ended up with

```
<?php

global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "ip_based_login";

$wpdb->query( 
    "UPDATE $table_name
    SET start='X', end='Y'"
 );


?>
```

It's not a solution to my initial question but it solved my problem.

Comment: WP has that and you can access it by `$wpdb->prefix`

Comment: Well, you're using `SELECT` instead of `UPDATE`, I think that's the main problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, that helped med solve my problem.

Comment: @Cynical I tried that and thought it would work, but got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two steps:

Find the WP tables with

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_ip_based_login';
```

Loop through your result and update with

```
UPDATE <tablename>
SET start = 'X', end = 'Y';
```

Comment: Thanks, even though I solved my problem, it's still nice to try and solve my initial question. I tried combining your code, to make it work in one go. Tried this
`<?php

global $wpdb;

$wpdb->query(
    "SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_ip_based_login';
    UPDATE <tablename>
    SET start = '2967400392', end = '2967400392';"
    
 );


?>`
But it didn't work

Comment: You have mistunderstood. I didn't say one go. I said two steps. You must select the table names (one query). Then *loop* through the results in PHP and fire one update query per table. You cannot use '<tablename> literally, but must replace it with a table Name.

Comment: No you can either ask for meta information (table names, columns, indices, etc) or query your tables. So you need two steps as mentioned. But what's so bad about that? Are you worried that your PHP script gets three lines longer? Or what is it that keeps you from just writing the loop?

Comment: It was out of pure curiosity. As I mentioned, I got it fixed by following RiggsFolly's suggestion. Was just curious about, whether or not, if it was possible with pure SQL commands. But thank you for clarifying!